# Animation on removeAllViews Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-animation, android-view

I have a class where I include another layout on a button click.  This included layout has some buttons and a code which executes on clicking these buttons.  I have used a counter which indicates the number of times the button is clicked.  First time clicking on the button includes the layout and the second time clicking removes the views and so on. Here's the code

```
public class Home extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

    int c = 0;
    Button bmain, bnew, bolder;
    RelativeLayout r1;
    View rootView;
    Animation slidedown, slideup;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);
         bmain = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn2);
         bmain.setOnClickListener(this);


        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        ViewGroup con = null;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
        FrameLayout flContainer = (FrameLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.flContainer);


        //Loading animation
        slidedown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.slide_down);
        slideup = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.slide_up);

        //The counter indicates the number of clicks.  
        //Needs to be replaced for a better solution.
        //If it's even add view
        if(c%2==0)
        {


            //Adding layout here
            flContainer.addView(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.test1,con,false ));

            //Starting Animation
            flContainer.startAnimation(slidedown);



            //After adding layout we can find the Id of the included layout and proceed from there 
            bnew = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btntest);
            bnew.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {            
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You Clicked New", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            });

            bolder = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btntest1);
            bolder.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Intent form = new Intent(getActivity(),FeedbackForm.class);
                    startActivity(form);

                }

            });

            c++;
        } //If ends here

        //If it's odd remove view
        else
        {


                flContainer.removeAllViews();
                flContainer.startAnimation(slideup);

                //flContainer.removeView(flContainer);
                //flContainer.removeView(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.test1, con, false));

                c++;
        }





        }       
}
```

The code at the end

```
                            flContainer.removeAllViews();
                flContainer.startAnimation(slideup);
```

removes the view but fails to process the animation.  I have tried using removeView but in that case the buttonclicks in the if statement fail to execute the second time.  What am I missing here?  How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple. You have to remove the view after the animation is finished. This can be achieved pretty simple, first you have to set an animation listener for your animation and in the `onAnimationEnd` callback - which is called when the animation is finished - you remove the views.

**EDIT:**

Replace this:

```
flContainer.removeAllViews();
flContainer.startAnimation(slideup);
```

With this:

```
slideup.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        flContainer.removeAllViews();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

    }
});
flContainer.startAnimation(slideup);
```

If there are any further problems let me know.

Comment: I want to remove the views on the button click rather than on animation end.  I tried using the code:   flContainer.removeView(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.test1, con, false));  It removes the view with animation but on clicking the button again to play the animation, the buttons in the layout which is included do not respond to clicks.

Comment: I have no idea what you are saying, but this code: `flContainer.removeView(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.test1, con, false));` is simply wrong. You are inflating a new view and then immediately try to remove it from the container. Pleas edit your question, explain exactly what it is you want to do.

Comment: In my home.xml file there is a button.  On clicking this button, a new layout is included.  This included layout in turn has some buttons whose click action is defined after I've included the layout.  The layout is included with an animation (slide up) as suggested by  the code. On clicking the button in my home.xml file again, the layout is removed.  The code 'flContainer.removeAllViews()' removes the view but it doesn't do it with animation slidedown as I want it to do.  How can I achieve it?

Comment: I already explained that in my answer, you literally just have to copy & paste my code.

Comment: Cheers! It worked.  Sorry didn't look at the full code.  My bad.  Thank you again champ!