# dynamically include a layout to another layout file inside a fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, include, fragment

I have a fragment layout to which i want to add another sub layout dynamically ,

I tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/22592269/8476022

sub-layout xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:hint="Question"
    android:textColor="@color/colorTextBlack"
    android:textSize="16dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

this is my main layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#f2f2f2"
android:orientation="vertical">
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/flContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

inside my fragment i included the sublayout

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_start_question, container, false);
     flContainer = (FrameLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.flContainer);
     flContainer.addView(R.layout.sub_layout);
    return v;
}
```

but i am getting error near addView the screenshot is below
[image]

can anyone please help to find the error

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are getting Error because
`addView(View child)` need parameter a `view` and you are adding `FrameLayout` which is `ViewGroup`

Try this way

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)   getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sub_layout, null);;
flContainer = (FrameLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.flContainer);
flContainer.addView(myView);
```

Answer (score 2):

Add view takes View object. You are passing the layout Id.

> addView(View view)

you do not pass the layout Id

> flContainer.addView(R.layout.sub_layout);// Wrong

First inflate a view using inflater then add it to container.

```
 View view=LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.yourView,null);
  yourContainer.addView(view);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to inflate layout to add the view refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2336047/5164673)

```
View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.sub_layout, null);
flContainer = (FrameLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.flContainer);
flContainer.addView(child);
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_start_question, container, false);
    // flContainer = (FrameLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.flContainer);
        // flContainer.addView(R.layout.sub_layout);
    LinearLayout linPhoneNumber = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.linPhoneNumber);
    View viewPhoneNumber  =  getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_contact_phone, null);
    LinearLayout linPhoneLayout = (LinearLayout) viewPhoneNumber.findViewById(R.id.linPhoneLayout);
    TextView txtPhoneNumber = (TextView) viewPhoneNumber.findViewById(R.id.txtPhoneNumber);
    txtPhoneNumber.setText(phone);
    linPhoneNumber.addView(viewPhoneNumber);
    return v;
}
```

put one linear layout in fragment_start_question.xml :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linPhoneNumber"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>
```

then fragment_contact_phone.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linPhoneLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_top_10"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="@dimen/margin_top">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgCall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_call" />

    <Textview
        android:id="@+id/txtPhoneNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_top_1"
        android:textColor="@color/menu_text_color"
        android:textSize="@dimen/margin_top_1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your onCreateView with the following,

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_start_question, container, false);
    flContainer = (FrameLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.flContainer);
    View subView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sub_layout, null);
    flContainer.addView(subView);
    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the layout id only,Define a layout first like:

```
LinearLayout sublayout = (LinearLayout)v.findViewBYId(R.layout.sub_layout)
flContainer.addView(sublayout);
```